# Can I use the expression « C’est le/un comble. » when I’m happy?

Tags: expressions

[image]

[Click here for definition (1)](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/comble/17400#160889)
[Click here for definition (2)](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/c%E2%80%99est_un_comble)

I would like to know if I can use this expression when I receive good news **qui dépasse tout ce que je pourrais imaginer** about another person (e.g. a friend) and I am happy for that person / friend or do I only use this expression when I get news **qui dépasse tout ce que je pourrais imaginer** and that makes my life harder?

Thank you for your help! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use that expression for good news.

*C'est un comble* is used to react to something you strongly disagree with, something outrageous.

On the other hand, you can use *comble* with a positive value in expressions like:

> *Je suis au comble de la joie !*

Comment: I would tend to agree with you, but the first example given in the question is actually quite positive, and I must say it doesn't sound too far off, even though I probably wouldn't use the expression there myself... or anywhere actually it's not really part of my usual registry, I find it a bit outdated and/or formal

Comment: @LaurentS. Not that positive in my opinion. The person telling that is possibly jealous or at least unhappy with the sequence of events.

Comment: aaah maybe you're right indeed... I'm too positive :-) "C'est un comble !" could maybe be here replaced by "Enfoiré !"...

Comment: @jlliagre The person (which is “I”) isn’t jealous. Simply, I hear good news of another person e.g. a friend **qui dépasse tout ce que je pourrais imaginer** and I’m happy for that person/friend.

Comment: @Laurent S. Since that confusion has been cleared up, do you have any thoughts?

Comment: @CubbyKushi both answer given hitherto confirm my initial feeling, I wouldn't use "c'est un comble !" for positive things as using it might be taken as irony.

Comment: @CubbyKushi If you are happy, you don't use *c'est un/le comble*.

Comment: @LaurentS. So the expression is only to be used in the face of news I consider bad. Thank you! Also, could you provide a source which shows that the expression is formal? The reason I ask is because *Académie Française* says it’s an “Exp. fam.” and **fam.** means familiar, right? : https://www.dictionnaire-academie.fr/article/A9C3066

Comment: @jlliagre Thank you!

Comment: @CubbyKushi > well I don't have a source, only my guts. I however can't think of any more formal way of expressing this idea, so if this is familiar, I wonder what the academy proposes as a more formal alternative....

Comment: @LaurentS. Probablement avec _summum_ ou _apogée_ ? Perso. je trouve l'expression familière mais _je suis au comble de la joie_, soutenu.

Answer (score 2):

No, you do not use this expression when your news are good; the proof of that is that, from the definition, you can equate this expression to "c'est insupportable", which means "it is unbearable".

The expression "c'est un comble", possibly slightly modified, is perfectly proper in all types of spoken language. Here are instances of its use in various conversations.

[Football](https://www.20minutes.fr/bordeaux/1559771-20150311-bordeaux-comble-girondins-redoutent-joueur-alignent-ironise-unfp), [Marlène Harnois](https://www.laprovence.com/article/sports/2506743/marlene-harnois-cest-un-comble.html), [froid chez soi](https://www.rtbf.be/vivacite/article/detail_c-est-un-comble-chez-moi-j-ai-froid-qui-se-reconnait-la-dedans?id=7540043), [garer sa voiture](https://www.dailymotion.com/video/xg2c91)

Comment: @ LPH Thank you!